# ValueError: Cannot load an array from Python 3.4 with numpy load() on Python 3.5

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, load

I have an array I created using Python 3.4

```
arr1 = "filename.npy" # created from Python 3.4 script
```

I then try to load this array in Python 3.5, and I get a Value Error in return:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load(arr1)
```

This outputs

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 406, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 673, in read_array
    array.shape = shape
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

So, I try to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open(arr1, "rb") as filebinary:
a = np.load(filebinary)
```

This outputs the same error. All the other arrays work (which I also created with Python 3.4, so that's not the problem).

I transferred this file remotely using `ssh`. Is it possible that the transferred file is corrupted? How can I check this?

Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Have you tried loading it with Python2?

Comment: To check whether the file is corrupted you could take the MD5 hashes using `md5sum` and check whether they match for the local and remote versions. In fact, you can often infer corruption just by comparing the exact file sizes.

Comment: @ali_m I understand comparing the array sizes. Could you explain what you mean by using MD5 hashes?

Comment: A [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) produces a fixed-length output from some arbitrarily-sized input data. They are designed such that there is a low probability for two non-identical inputs to yield the same hash value (which is known as a "hash collision"), which makes them a convenient way to check whether two files are identical. For example,`~$ md5sum filename.npy` will give you a 32 character hex string. You could do this for your local and remote copies and compare the strings. If they are the same then your files are (almost certainly) identical.